# Change Tab Colour and Periodically Refresh

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where each sheet has a value in cell C94.  I want the tab colour to change depending on the value in this cell.  I then want the worksheet to refresh every 60 seconds or so, and update all the tab colours in the workbook.

So far, I have this code entered on to each of the tabs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Range("$C$94").Value
    Case "In Progress"
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 43
    Case "Missed Lay"
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
    Case "Action Required"
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
    Case "Complete"
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 1
    Case Else
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Select
End Sub
```

This works and updates whenever I manually change data in a cell and hit enter.  How do I get this to refresh the tab colour without needing to change the value and hit enter?  Is it possible to get this to refresh every 60 seconds, or when data is changed in a cell in any other worksheet in the workbook?  Either would be a suitable solution for my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way is to let Excel update all sheets

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Tab
            Select Case ws.Range("C94").Value2
                Case "In Progress":     .ColorIndex = 43
                Case "Missed Lay":      .ColorIndex = 3
                Case "Action Required": .ColorIndex = 45
                Case "Complete":        .ColorIndex = 1
                Case Else:              .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End Select
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

There are ways to monitor changes every minute, but they will use up more resources

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Paul - I've just tried this in the ThisWorkbook module but doesnt seem to be working. None of the tabs are changing colour now. Have I missed something? Or do i need to make any declarations etc?

Comment: OK did that. When updating C94, it opens up the VBA editor at the break point

Comment: OK that code is a definite improvement on mine as it is stored in one place, rather than in the code for each sheet. So much appreciated! However, I still have the same problem with colours not updating.. I'm still stuck in the position where in order to update the colour of the tab, I need to open the sheet, make a change to the data and then hit enter. Ideally, when data in sheet1 is updated, I'd like the tabs on all other sheets in the book to update at the same time. - based on their individual values in each C94 (Which will be different per sheet and change over time).

Comment: Got it - the code will need to check all sheets for every change event on any sheet; give me a momemnt

Comment: Paul, you sir, are a legend!! Thank you so much for your help, it works perfectly now! I cannot thank you enough!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped ! (as a reference for others please accept the answer - click on the check-mark under the down arrow)